# Using interfaces with or operator

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code, interface

Let's say we have a slider component that have an Input
The Input can take either Products or Teasers

`public productsWithTeasers: (Product | Teaser)[];`

doing this will give an error in vs code

```
<div *ngFor="let product of productsWithTeasers"> {{ product.externalId }}</div>
```

`Identifier 'externalId' is not defined. '<anonymous>' does not contain such a memberAngular`

What is the proper way to do this?

note: The 2 objects are not similar so using extend in interfaces is not what I'm looking for :)

Comment: Don't you want to declare it as `productsWithTeasers: Product[] | Teaser[];` ?

Comment: @DaggeJ I guess I can but the outcome is the same..

Comment: ...ok, maybe wrapping it in an interface might help... `productsWithTeasers: productOrTeaser[]`  - `interface productOrTeaser { data: Product | Teaser }`

Comment: Do both types have an `externalId` property?

Comment: @VLAZ no.. only the product... but this is not a runtime error.. it does work.. but the angular language service throws the error in vs code (at least I think it's the language service)

Comment: @Mackelito ok...this sounds like exactly your problem then. You define a union type of two but items from that union type are not guaranteed to have `externalId` member. So, trying to use the property that might not be there then the compiler throws an error.

Comment: @VLAZ I was kind of expecting it to accept that it could be either one and allow properties from both... ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add some extra types to your `productsWithTeasers`. It certainly removed the errors from my VS Code.

`productsWithTeasers: (Product | Teaser)[] | Product[] | Teaser[]`;

This way, the array can be a mix of Teasers and Products, or contain only Teasers or only Products.

Here is a minimal example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-afcby5

html:

```
<div *ngFor="let prod of products">
  {{prod?.myProdAttribute}}
</div>
```

component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'button-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'button-overview-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['button-overview-example.css'],
})
export class ButtonOverviewExample {
  products: (Product | Teaser)[] | Product[] | Teaser[] = [{myProdAttribute: 'asd'},{myTeaserAttribute: 'fgdfg'}];
}

export class Product {
  myProdAttribute: string;
}

export class Teaser {
  myTeaserAttribute: string;
}
```

Comment: Currently using <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'product'"> so null should never happen :)

Comment: Ok, but did it work to add the extra types? That was my main point :)

Comment: @Mackelito Did you figure it out with another solution?

Comment: not really.. we dropped it as it is ont affecting the application.. well take another look later on :)